# How to Recreate the top most Activity in Android, without restarting the app from the first page in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

It is said that, when we change the theme, we have to recreate the current activity in android to take it effect.

In `Xamarin.Forms` when I get the current activity it always returns me `MainActivity`. So if I recreate the top most activity, it starts from the first page instead of refreshing the current page.

Is there any way through which, I can recreate the activity and still be on the page where I am.

EX :

Current Behavior : Page A -> B -> C -> D -> Recreate -> Starts From A, again.

Expected Behavior : Page A -> B -> C -> D -> Recreate -> Should b on D only and still should able to change the theme.

I realized that, `Xamarin.Forms` pushes all content pages as Fragments inside the `MainActivity`. So, any way through which, Activity gets recreated but still hold all of it's loaded Fragments load again?

My implementation is simple. when I change the theme, I call the platform specific Dependency service method:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(NativeServices))]
namespace XFThemes.Droid.Dependencies
{
    public class NativeServices : INativeServices
    {
        public void OnThemeChanged(ThemeManager.Themes theme)
        {            
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Recreate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only NavigationPage and TabbedPage host fragments... You can always recreate the Form's navigation Page stack after you change the Android theme and perform a push to the Page D.

Comment: @SushiHangover : That would be hard part of doing it way. Any way through which we can Push each ContentPage as it's own separate Android Activity rather than Fragments?

Comment: You can host each `ContentPage` in an different Activity, but then you are using Android navigation, etc.. and not any of the Form-based services provided... (basically you are just using the embedding features at that point) IMHO: the added coding overhead to mange Pages within Activities would just drive me to use native android layouts (and it has ;-) Actually recreating the Form's nav stack is really easy, assuming you are using some form of MVC/MVVM/Viper/... and your Form's pages are truly independent of their model.